# jQuery function with multiple events that happen one at a time

Tags: jquery, events, listener

I have a rather simple questions. I'd like to make a jquery function work so when I mouseenter a div, multiple events happen, one at a time, not all together. Would I simply delay?

HTML:

```
<div class="all">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="trashwrapper">
<div class="trash"></div>
</div>
<div class="delete">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".trashwrapper").on("mouseenter", function(){
   $(".delete").animate({width: "150px"}, 300);
   $(".delete").text("Delete?");
}).on("mouseleave", function(){
   $(".delete").empty("Delete?");
   $(".delete").animate({width: "0px"}, 300);
});
```

I'd like it so my .delete width is animated to 150px, THEN the "Delete?" text appears. Right now, the "Delete?" text pretty much appears while .delete is animating.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do something after the animate function is complete. Then it has a parameter to supply a callback function. use that. There are [examples in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Btw. I think that `.empty()` doesn't accept any parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter to the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function is a callback function for when the animation completes.  So you can set the text after the animation is done

```
$(".trashwrapper").on("mouseenter", function(){
   $(".delete").animate({width: "150px"}, 300, function () {
         $(".delete").text("Delete?");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the callback function:

```
$(".trashwrapper").on("mouseenter", function(){
   $(".delete").animate({width: "150px"}, 300,function(){
      $(this).text("Delete?");
   });
 }).on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(".delete").animate({width: "0px"}, 300, function(){
      $(this).empty("Delete?");
   });
 });
```

which will fetch you desired result (text change after animation)